# Emacs and Helm - How to not show 'buffer-history' when i do 'kill-buffer'

Tags: emacs, emacs-helm

I use [`helm`](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm), and every time I do <kbd>C-x k</kbd> (`kill-buffer`) it shows my "kill-buffer History" at the top.

[image: screenshot]

Is there a way to just show just the "kill-buffer" section? I don't use "kill-buffer History" at all. Also, Emacs froze a couple of times when I tried to kill a buffer! So I don't want that section any more :-)

Configuration-wise, I just have:

```
(helm-mode 1)
```

Nothing else.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Ask the helm list if you don't get an answer here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/emacs-helm

Answer (score -1):

Use projectile package which provides various to list buffers which should be based on a)major-mode, b)derived mode, c)only project files, d) only test files. etc...

If you want to use please try emacs prelude(better preconfigured) https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude.